# Using PyShp to create polygon shapefiles?

Tags: pyshp

I have a script for creating points shapefiles, but I can not fix it for make a new polyline shp file.

I have obtained the data from a excel file and extract data in three differents lists
Lon,lat,label

```
import shapefile as shp
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
r = 'myfile.xlsm'


wb = load_workbook(filename= r, data_only=True, use_iterators = True)  
ws = wb['Export_Area']
cell_range = ws ['B5:D9']
tuple(ws.iter_rows('B5:D9'))
lista = []
for row in ws.iter_rows('B5:D9'):
    for cell in row:
        lista.append(cell.value)
        Longitud_area = (lista[1:len(lista):3])
        latitud_area = (lista[0:len(lista):3])
        puntos_area = (lista[2:len(lista):3])
```

## creating the shp file

```
out_file = 'ExportArea.shp'


x,y,id_no=Longitud_area,latitud_area,puntos_area
logic = [True,False,True]
w = shp.Writer(shp.POINT)
w.autoBalance = 1 #ensures gemoetry and attributes match
w.field('X','F',10,5)
w.field('Y','F',10,5) #float - needed for coordinates
w.field('etiqueta','D') #date


for j,k in enumerate(x):
    w.point(k,y[j]) #write the geometry
    w.record(k,y[j],puntos_area[j]) #write the attributes
```

## creating the prj file.

```
prj = open(out_file +'.prj', 'w')
proyeccion      ="GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]'
prj.write(proyeccion)
```

It works fine for a point shp file but I can not see how to do the loop for making a poly shp file

Comment: A polyline is a simple list of points (w.line(parts=[[[1,5],[5,5],[5,1],[3,3],[1,1]]]))

Comment: I know, but I have data into three lists. I do not like to enter that one by one

Comment: To read an Excel file, use [Pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063458/reading-an-excel-file-in-python-using-pandas) and everything will be clearer (three lists ?)

Comment: longitud    [-2.7692601473009155, -2.7362662697828974, -2.3913741501505776, -2.424387612708171, -2.7692601473009155]
latitud  [43.82769682706945, 43.66046724635432, 43.69596983959721, 43.86319942031234, 43.82769682706945]    label['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', None]

Answer (score 1):

If you want the coordinates (longitud, latitud) in a single list, use the function `zip()`

```
longitud= [-2.7692601473009155, -2.7362662697828974, -2.3913741501505776, -2.424387612708171, -2.7692601473009155]
latitud= [43.82769682706945, 43.66046724635432, 43.69596983959721, 43.86319942031234, 43.82769682706945]
coord = zip(longitud, latitud)
print coord
[(-2.7692601473009155, 43.82769682706945), (-2.7362662697828974, 43.66046724635432), (-2.3913741501505776, 43.69596983959721), (-2.424387612708171, 43.86319942031234), (-2.7692601473009155, 43.82769682706945)]
```

For reading an Excel file it is easiest now to use the [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) module.

```
import pandas as pd
xl = pd.ExcelFile("mispuntos.xlsx")
print xl.sheet_names
[u'mispuntos']
# create a pandas dataframe
df = xl.parse('mispuntos')
print df.columns
Index([u'longitud', u'latitud', u'label'], dtype='object')
print df.head()
   longitud   latitud   label
0 -2.769260  43.827697     A
1 -2.736266  43.660467     B
2 -2.391374  43.695970     C
3 -2.424388  43.863199     D
4 -2.769260  43.827697   NaN
```

Point shapefile

```
import shapefile
w = shp.Writer(shp.POINT)
w.field('X','F',10,5)
w.field('Y','F',10,5) #float - needed for coordinates
w.field('label')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   w.point(row['longitud'],row['latitud'])
   w.record(row['longitud'],row['latitud'],str(row['label']))
w.save('resulting')
```

Now, a polyline

```
# extract the 3 first rows of the dataframe
df2=df[0:3] # slicing
line = [[row['longitud'],row['latitud']] for index, row in df2.iterrows()]
print line # = list of points)
[[-2.7692601473, 43.8276968271], [-2.73626626978, 43.6604672464], [-2.39137415015, 43.6959698396]]
# write the polyline shapefile
w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POLYLINE)
w.field('label') 
w.line(parts=([line]))
w.record('a')
w.save('line')
```

Result

[image]

If you wish to go further, use [GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/) (geospatial Pandas, the geometric operations are performed by [shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html), file access by [Fiona](http://toblerity.github.com/fiona/manual.html), not PyShp, and plotting by [descartes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/descartes) and [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/))

Comment: Thanks. I will follow your advise. I will try GeoPandas. Meanwhile I use this sollution

Comment: Hi. I´m trying to understand the reading mode in Pandas but I can not find how do I read some cells into a ExcelBook. The points are inside a sheet inside a workbook. How can I read some cells with pandas? For example [B5:C34] into a work sheet into a work book