# Generating shapefile of polylines using pyshp from a csv file and opening file in qgis

Tags: qgis, python, pyshp

I tried the solution posted in:

- [Creating Polyline from GML using PyShp?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74767/pyshp-1-2-creating-polyline-from-gml),
- [Using PyShp to convert polygons in *.csv to *.shp files?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70786/using-the-python-shape-library-pyshp-how-to-convert-polygons-in-csv-file-to) and
- [Using PyShp to create polygon shapefiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119160/poly-shapefile-using-pyshp)

to generate polylines from a csv file.

When I load the shapefile into QGIS, it is not displaying the lines.

Is this a known issue with QGIS?

I am using QGIS 2.8.2 on a Mac.

I can see that the coordinates are in the shapefile when I do this:

```
import shapefile
test = shapefile.Reader(shpFilePath)
shapes = test.shapes()

for i in xrange(0,len(shapes)):
    x = shapes[i]
    a = x.__geo_interface__
    print a['coordinates']
```

Is there another software we could use to view the shapefiles?

Comment: Perhaps the spatial reference isn't set or doesn't match the data. Can you give a list of a few coordinates and spatial reference please. The *exact* implementation of the 3 links might be significant, can you post that also. Please edit your question to include the relevant details.